# Instanciar classe anotada com herança do Hibernate usando CDI

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, herança, cdi

Boa tarde,

Estou criando um projeto usando `JSF`, `CDI`, `Bootstrap` e `Hibernate`.

Gostaria por favor de saber como trabalhar com o seguinte problema, eu criei um conjunto de classes para representar uma entidade de pessoa `física` ou `jurídica`. A estrutura ficou a seguinte:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=1)
@Named("clientePojo")
public abstract class Cliente extends Persistent {

    public enum TipoCliente {

        FISICA('F', "Física"), 
        JURIDICA('J', "Juridica");

        private final char tipo;
        private final String descricao;

        private TipoCliente(char tipo, String descricao) {
            this.tipo = tipo;
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public static TipoCliente valueOf(char sigla) {

            switch (sigla) {
            case 'F':
                return TipoCliente.FISICA;
            case 'J':
                return TipoCliente.JURIDICA;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        public char getTipo() {
            return tipo;
        }

        public String getDescricao() {
            return descricao;
        }
    }

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String tipo;

    // getter e setter  
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="F")
public class ClienteFisico extends Cliente {

    private String nome;

    private Date dataNascimento;

    private String identidade;

    private String cpf;

    // getter e setter
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="J")
public class ClienteJuridico extends Cliente {

    private String razaoSocial;
    private String nomeFantasia;
    private String cnpj;

    // getter e setter
}
```

Como eu devo tratar este caso para instanciar no `bean`?
Já que o formulário de cadastro você seleciona se o tipo é físico ou jurídico.

Answer (score 2):

Recupere se o tipo de pessoa a ser cadastrada pelo formulário é Física ou Jurídica e instancie um objeto do tipo que você desejar.

Ex.:

```
if (TipoCliente.FISICO == form.getTipoPessoaValue()) {
   ClienteFisico cliente = new ClienteFisico();
   // insira seus setters aqui
}
```

Você pode instanciar um objeto de uma classe filha, e mesmo assim, setar atributos que são representados pela superclasse (como no caso de Cliente e ClienteFisico).

**Obs.:** É recomendado que você não manipule dados de entidades diretamente. Para isso, usasse a utilização de [Data Transfer Objects](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_Transfer%C3%AAncia_de_Dados) ou DTO's. Você teria algo como "ClienteDTO" e etc.

Comment: Cara, eu vou alterar o projeto e vou separar mais as classes. Mas me fica a dúvida se isso não vai dar problema no jsf

Comment: Outra dúvida é em que momento eu instancio o objeto, porque não daria pal se eu fizer uma validação ou algo com ajax não?

Comment: Daria sim. Qualquer que seja a biblioteca de componentes que vc está usando com o JSF (primefaces ou richfaces), você tem atributos de elementos que são acionados de forma assíncrona. Sugiro que você dê uma olhada na documentação do componente da biblioteca que você esteja utilizando. Vai ser moleza ;)

Comment: Vou testar e qualquer dúvida te falo!

Comment: Você poderia postar na resposta o exemplo do DTO como ficaria por favor

Comment: Você apenas cria uma classe idêntica à ClienteFisico, porém, com nome ClienteFisicoDTO. Essa nova classe DTO não terá anotações de @Entity e nem quaisquer outras. Ela só servirá como uma representação do seu ClienteFisico. Onde você recupera o tipo de cliente (físico ou jurídico) e instância um novo ClienteFisico, você deve instânciar um ClienteFisicoDTO e logo depois do seu objeto DTO ser preenchido com os dados, aí sim você seta os atributos desse objeto DTO para o Entity (ClienteFisico). Colocarei o exemplo do código daqui a pouco caso você não consiga. (Estou pelo celular rs).